# what is the use of declaring the same struct 2 times for making a constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm still learning and this code really confuse me.

```
struct Sales_data;
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item);

struct Sales_data {
  Sales_data::Sales_data(std::istream &is) {
    read(is, *this);
  }

  std::string bookNo;
  unsigned units_sold = 0;
  double revenue = 0.0;
};
```

That code basically use 2 `struct Sales_data` for making a single `Sales_data(std::istream &is) {}` constructor.

why not just do it like this?

```
struct Sales_data {
  Sales_data(std::istream &is) {
    read(is, *this);
  }

  std::string bookNo;
  unsigned units_sold = 0;
  double revenue = 0.0;
};
```

Comment: It's a forward declaration, that is needed for the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Sales_data;
```

is a forward declaration that can be used to establish the prototype for the free function `read`.

after that it is implemented.

Since the constructor uses the read function it needs to be declared before the actual struct.

Answer (score 0):

The code declares a `read` function and the declaration of this read function needs a declaration of the class:

```
struct Sales_data;
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item);
```

This function is decalred before the class is defined, because the class definition is calling the function:

```
struct Sales_data {
  Sales_data::Sales_data(std::istream &is) {
    read(is, *this);
  }

  std::string bookNo;
  unsigned units_sold = 0;
  double revenue = 0.0;
};
```

Somewhere down the line there must be a definition for `read(std::istream&,Sales_data)` otherwise there will be a linker error.

> why not just do it like this? [...]

Because you need at least a declaration of `read(std::istream&,Sales_data)` to be able to call it. If you try your code you will get a compiler error because no `read` function has been declared.